# how to determine memory type(lpddr) and memory frequency for android kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am stuck trying to determine the ram type (lpddr) and ram frequency in Mhz for an Android device. any available resources or mappings I can refer to?

is it possible to calculate such info using totalMem info?

get ram type and ram frequency